# [Spring MVC]- How can I retrieve all form params in a map?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to retrieve all form Params in a map

Somthing like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(Map<String, Object> formParams) {
    //implementation
}
```

PS: I'am using **Spring MVC (Version 4.1.1.RELEASE)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply a @RequestParam annotation to the parameter. See more here : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam

"When an @RequestParam annotation is used on a Map or MultiValueMap argument, the map is populated with all request parameters."